# How to represent skewness(X) in terms of the expected value?

Tags: probability, variance, random-variable, expected-value, skewness

Let $X$ be the random variable. $E(X)$ is the expected value of $X$

Then

$Var(X)$ = $E(X^2)$ − $[E(X)]^2$

where $Var(X)$ is the variance of $X$

Then how to represent skewness(X) in terms of the expected value.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Definition, replace $\mu$ with $\mathbb{E}(X)$.

Comment: You cannot, because skewness is a completely different property.  Indeed, by adding a constant to $X$ you can make $E(X)$ anything you like without changing the skewness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every moment/standardised moment is expressed in terms of some kind of expected value. For example, you've expressed the variance using expected value. But you couldn't do it using only the expected value of $X$, i.e. $E[X]$, since you cannot express $E[X^2]$ using $E[X]$ only. Similarly, the skewness can be expressed in terms of *expectations* as follows: $$E\left[\left(\frac{(X-E[X])^3}{\operatorname{var}(X)^{3/2}}\right)\right]$$

But, it cannot be expressed using only $E[X]$.